# is there any other method to fetch the data from json array other then $.each loop

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to retrieve the values from `json` multidimensional array and I wanted to compare the `id` from each table. But using `$each` loop I am not able to do it. Is there any other method to do it?

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({

        url : "http://ip/App/xxx/yyy",
        type:"GET",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{param:"no"},
        success: function(json)
        {
            var event1=json.event1;
            var media1=json.media;
            var DOM=$('#DOM');
            var path="http://ip/App/";
            $.each(event1,function(key,value) 
            { 

            DOM.append("<li><h3>"+value.event_id+"</h3><p>"+value.event_title+
                       "</p><p>"+value.event_discription+"</p><p>"+
                       value.event_summary+"</p><p>"+
                       value.event_start_date+"</p></li>")

            });
            $.each(media1,function(key,value) 
            { 
             DOM.append('<li><p><img src='+path+value.media_path+' alt=""  />
                         </p><p>'+value.media_id+'</p></li>');

            });


        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("check ur connection/ip"+e);
        }
    });
});
```

I want to compare `id` of each array.

Comment: _But using $each loop I am not able to do it_ - Why not?  Is there an error?

Comment: You want to compare what to what exactly?

Comment: Any loop could do, you don't even need to use `$.each()` at all.

Comment: but how to retrieve the  values from array can any one explain with an example..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var event1=json.event1;
var media1=json.media;
var DOM=$('#DOM');
var path="http://ip/App/";

for (var i = 0; i < event1.length; i++) {
var event_id = event1[i].event_id;
var event_title = event1[i].event_title;
// etc...
}
```

Comment: Hi @SharanRai, what do you mean? Could you provide an example of your what your JSON response is like please?

Comment: thanks for the reply @ rharvey. My json array contains values which are retrieved from different tables .. which are named like event1, media...etc so it is a multidimensional array. it cannot retrieve values with the method you specified..

Comment: Hi @SharanRai, would you say your JSON looks like this: {"event1":[{"event_id":1,"event_title":"event 1"},{...}],"media":[{...},{...}]}